# The object doesn't manage forEach Properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I have a script that use the method forEach that work on some Firefox browser but never on IE11.

The error is : The object doesn't manage forEach Properties

```
var clearContent = function clearContent() {
  var allDistricts = document.querySelectorAll(".district");
  allDistricts.forEach(function(item) {
    item.style.display = "none";
  });
};
```

Oh can I replace the method forEach easily ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use simple `for` loop:

```
 var clearContent = function clearContent() {
    var allDistricts = document.querySelectorAll('.district');
    for (var i=0; i<allDistricts.length; i++) {
      allDistricts[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  };
```

Comment: Thank you, indeed the problem wans't the forEach but the querySelectorAll.

Answer (score 2):

`NodeList.querySelectorAll` is a somewhat new function that is not supported on obsolete browsers. (`querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`)

[MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) it was first supported on Chrome 51 and FF 50, which were only released a couple of years ago (and, of course, it isn't supported at all on IE, which was released in 2013).

For a polyfill, you can use this:

```
if (window.NodeList && !NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
  NodeList.prototype.forEach = function (callback, thisArg) {
    thisArg = thisArg || window;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
      callback.call(thisArg, this[i], i, this);
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: How does this resolve the error 
`The error is : The object doesn't manage forEach Properties`
as mentioned bu OP?

Comment: If he uses the polyfill, he *will* be able to use `forEach` on `NodeList`s.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)